Does the Truth not exists or does it seems to not exists due to our abstraction?
I will give an example to illustrate my question :
We sometimes hear something like : "All the [population of a country] are [stereotypes]".
I think we all know that, for a certain number of people, this sentence isn't true, ALL people do not have the SAME caracteristic (except biological of course). So does it mean that The Truth does not exist (so the [stereotype] does not really exist) or that our abstraction is an obstacle for the Truth (so that the [population of a country] is an abstraction that is too large to fit the [stereotype]) ?
So we can summarize our problem with : Does our language of overgeneralization hides the truth of our world or does the truth not exist because the Truth is actually our point of view ?

Please clarify what you mean by "the Truth", written with capital intial, and also what you mean by "the truth of our world"; thanks.

Well, if "the Truth is actually our point of view" then it will greatly simplify a lot of things. Who wins if two people disagree though?

I think this is partially answered by Is there a logic of non-universal class characteristics? from March of last year.

I think what you are referring to is this: there are sentences such as "dogs have four legs" that are true, yet if you try to define what they mean formally, it's hard to find a formal interpretation that is also true. For example, it's not true that "for all x, if x is a dog then x has four legs" because there are dogs that are missing legs.
This sort of problem seems to arise for practically all sentences that deal with the temporal world (which includes all physical and mental objects). I'm not sure the word "abstraction" is really the right one; I'd prefer "formalization" or maybe "idealization", but yes, it is the case that propositions that seem unproblematically true come to seem problematic when subjected to analysis. You could use this problem as a reason to doubt that genuine truth exists, but I prefer the alternative understanding: this problem shows that formalization is an artificial process that does not preserve truth. It is true that dogs have four legs; what is not true is the formalizations you try to derive from this.

Proof that dogs have an infinite number of legs: Doges have two legs in back, and forelegs in front. Two plus fore is six, which is an even number, but certainly an odd number of legs for a dog. The only number which is both even and odd is infinity. QED...

The problem is that as stated, the assertion that dogs have four legs is not always true. It is the expected case on a healthy intact dog, but it does depend on an implied assumption. If you are concerned about truth, never mind Truth, you_must_ take care to enumerate all the assumptions being made, and accept that any case not explicitly covered is not guaranteed to be true. The problem isn't that truth doesn't exist, but that we don't rigorously restrict ourselves to it... and usually don't have to do so if an approximation works well enough.

@keshlam, you are doing exactly what I said is not truth-preserving.

The reference implementation of Dog has 4 legs.

+1 Truth as agreement of assertion with observation exists for oneself, so if one finds a 3-legged dog the validity of the agreement is one's own to re-qualify. "[If] this conformity is seen only as a relationship between things which are present-at-hand [i.e. assertion and observation]. . . then the relation shows itself as an agreement of two things which are present-at-hand, an agreement which is present-at-hand itself." GA2 p.267.

I think, for sufficiently abstract questions, you can find different answers with different shades of truth. And even the same answer to exactly the same question can appear to you in different shades of truthfulness, depending on the place, mood, time of the day.
Even obviously opposite answers to the same question can have a flavor of truthfulness, if you manage to open your mind, of course.

Truthiness?
There are a bunch of thoughts about true/false statements. 1+1=2... I think we all kind of accept that one. The sun will rise tomorrow... yeah, gonna give that a high probability too. But, it's not the same.
Here's a good though experiment: Is it possible that the sun will explode tomorrow? If it does, will 1+1=2 still, even if no one is around?
We can't conceive of a world where 1+1 doesnt equal 2, but we can concieve of one where nothing exists at all. There could be a world where there are cats with duck beaks, but the cat-ducks wont be able to sit in chairs and pick them up at the same time. You can't make a circle a square without it no longer being a square or a circle. God can't make a bolder so big he* cant push it up a hill... etc
Paradoxes are the best objective truth measure we have
But, directly answering your question... the answer is:
Yes - there are certain truths, until we have the scope to learn otherwise. That doesnt mean all opinions are valid. And pejorative statements about people are terrible logically

The truth is, in itself, a language capability: it is an overgeneralization, a generic instance of proof, that can be only sufficient while not being necessary.

A sufficient condition is a condition or set of conditions that will
produce the event. A necessary condition must be there, but it alone
does not provide sufficient cause for the occurrence of the event.
Only the sufficient grounds can do this. In other words, all of the
necessary elements must be there.
A sufficient condition is a condition or set of conditions that will produce the event. A necessary condition must be there, but it alone does not provide sufficient cause for the occurrence of the event. Only the sufficient grounds can do this. In other words, all of the necessary elements must be there [1].


For some statements, the statements' truth value is just an abstract, collective state of mind of those people who have an opinion about it. If humans are the only entity that reasons about their truth, there is no arbiter who can distinguish between "this is really true" and "this is actually false, but people think to know otherwise".
Examples of such statements are abstract theorems in mathematics whose truth is "decided" in peoples minds.

Regarding
"does the truth not exist because the Truth is actually our point of view"
I once wrote some answer on reality / what is real while also addressing truth:
What has any effect is real.
Falsehoods, delusions, illusions, abstract concepts, the hypothetical have an effect above nothing. Therefore, they are real. Real by at least their effect.
Falsehoods and delusions shaped civilizations.
Sciences constantly dwell in the hypothetical to disprove statements.
Sciences apply incomplete models and approximations (e.g. mass points, Newtons mechanics) instead of correct representations of "reality" all over the place.
Still, one can not deny their effect, their utility and call these things unreal.
When people call these things unreal they usually identify real things by their expected essence, not their effect or their actual essence. This is a mistake. They will call it unreal but suffer its effect and act upon it anyway.
When Kant stated "I think, therefore I am.", he only experienced the effect of his thoughts onto himself. He did not identify the essence of his thoughts.
Here, also be aware of the differences between effect, utility and truth:
Effect is simply what causes a state difference between the world where the effect applied and the world where it didn't (and other things being the same aka. experimental conditions).
Utility requires effect but is highly subjective. An effect, that is good for you, may be bad for someone else.
Truth does not imply utility. A truth may be useful.
Falsehood does not imply utility. A falsehood may be useful.
Truth is overrated and does not define (complete) reality.
